# Php, how 'inject' a variable (and value) in memory

Tags: php, memory, global

I'm looking for a way to :

1. define a **php** global variable:

   - If a execute a php file A, file B ... I can access this variable while apache is running.
2. 'hide' the value of this variable

   - I don't want the value of this variable be findable if someone access to the server and search (via a grep -nri by example) the value of this variable in a PHP file

My question is:

- Is there a way for inject a global persistent (while Apache running) variable in memory without define its value in any file in the server ?

=> if I create a simple PHP form where the user can set and submit the value of this variable, how can I save the value of this variable for it can be accessible from any PHP file ?

Question bonus:

- Is there a way for inject an usable PHP variable via a C or JAVA program ? (via a compiled program)

Comment: This raises the question: why do you want to do this?

Comment: PHP offers some functions to access shared memory (see http://php.net/manual/en/intro.sem.php), but if you want to truly hide the value from other processes on the operating system then you'll need to encrypt the contents somehow.

Comment: Unless you want to be restarting your server by hand every single time, not leaving any trace on disk is very impractical. File permissions are usually used to solve that problem. What's so special about your use case that you can't use techniques used by countless sys admins all over the planet?

Comment: Theoretically you could write an Apache module to set an environment variable, compile it into Apache and run that... technically the value would still be defined in a file on the server - but it would be a binary. I'm really not seeing the point though...

Comment: @PeeHaa > the reason : I want protect the value of a data. If the value of the variable is in a file, then this is more easy to find it instead if I inject the value of this variable in the memory.

Comment: You can protect the value of the variable by simply putting it into a PHP script outside the docroot with the relevant user access permissions though... I'm still not setting the point. **Who** are you trying to prevent access to - and **how** would they be accessing it?

Comment: Who and how, if a user can access to the server and get sames permissions than apache (via come hack). I want prevent this case

Comment: If a user can get that kind of access to your server then you're probably dead in the water either way.

Comment: I agree :) but dump variables in memory take more time than a simple recursive grep search :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your PHP script and/or program. If you can do it in `.htacces`, you can do it in your vhost configuration.

```
echo $_SERVER['MY_VAR']
```

There's also PHP functions to set your PHP `ini` values.

In your **first file**

```
<?php
$uniqid="Hello";
putenv("UNIQID=$uniqid");
?>
```

In your **second file**

```
<?php echo getenv('UNIQID') ?>
```

I'm not sure about a way to populate `$ENV`, or is `SetEnv` will do it. It's worth investigating a `var_dump($ENV)` with the above.

**Inject PHP variable into JAVA**

```
Process runtime = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("php -r  'echo getenv(\'UNIQID\');'");
```

Comment: @downvoter, can I know reason downvote or good solution for this?